# GMSPolygon with a UIImage in it or GMSGroundOverlay

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios, gmsgroundoverlay

I want to draw a GMSPolygon with an image in it or crop a GMSGroundOverlay's image.

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:48.774052
                                                            longitude:-110.375980
                                                                 zoom:0];
mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;

GMSMutablePath *shapePath = [[GMSMutablePath alloc] init];
[shapePath addLatitude:48.774052 longitude:-110.375980];
[shapePath addLatitude:40.676195 longitude:-123.911136];
[shapePath addLatitude:33.682907 longitude:-101.762699];

/*** **/
GMSCoordinateBounds *overlayBounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithPath:shapePath];

UIImage *icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"usaimages.jpg"];
GMSGroundOverlay *overlay =
[GMSGroundOverlay groundOverlayWithBounds:overlayBounds icon:icon];
overlay.bearing = 0;
overlay.map = mapView_;
    /*** **/

GMSPolygon *shape = [GMSPolygon polygonWithPath:shapePath];
shape.strokeWidth= 2;
shape.title=@"xx";
shape.fillColor= [UIColor redColor];
//shape.strokeColor= [UIColor brownColor];
shape.map=mapView_;

self.view = mapView_;
mapView_.delegate=self;
```

Now this is what I see:

[image]

and this is what I want to see:

[image]

I want to put the flag into GMSPolygon or get the same result by cropping GMSGroundOverlay's icon. I don't which is possible or how I can do it.

Answer (score 2):

crop the image first and then use.i suggest to use Gmsgroundoverlay  as u will have a lot of controll over the image.like angle for alingment,rotation etc